# SQL server multi-period comparison

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table `T1` (sample shown), which shows the category for each client (each with a unique ID) on a specific date and his category on the next date:

```
+------------+----------------+----------+---------------+
|    DATE    |       ID       |   STAGE  |   STAGE_NEXT  |    
+------------+----------------+----------+---------------+
| 2014-07-01 | 10010101841033 |        1 |             1 |
| 2015-07-01 | 74610108542146 |        1 |             1 |
| 2014-10-01 | 47970108841775 |        3 |             3 |
| 2014-10-01 | 48870108841816 |        2 |             3 |
| 2014-10-01 | 32910097439541 |        1 |             1 |
| 2016-04-01 | 46930097440855 |        2 |             3 |
| 2016-04-01 | 47380097440931 |        2 |             3 |
| 2016-04-01 | 54560097441411 |        3 |             3 |
+------------+----------------+----------+---------------+
```

Table info:
- Rows: 513,000
- Date range: 2013-01-01 to 2019-10-01
- Stages: 1 - 3

I need to create a new column in `T1`, which will flag the date a client moved to Stage 1 if at any point he was in Stage 3. For example if we take 1 client from `T1` by using this code:

```
SELECT [DATE], ID, STAGE, STAGE_NEXT
FROM T1
WHERE ID = '74610108542146'
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

We get the following result:

```
+------------+----------------+-------+------------+
|    DATE    |       ID       | STAGE | STAGE_NEXT |
+------------+----------------+-------+------------+
| 2015-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |
| 2015-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |
| 2016-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 2          |
| 2016-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 1          |
| 2016-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |
| 2016-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 2          |
| 2017-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 3          |
| 2017-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     3 | 3          |
| 2017-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     3 | 2          |
| 2017-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 1          |
| 2018-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |
| 2018-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | NULL       |
+------------+----------------+-------+------------+
```

After the new column with the flag is added to `T1` we should be able to get the following result using this code on `T1`:

```
SELECT [DATE], ID, STAGE, STAGE_NEXT, FLAG
FROM T1
WHERE ID = '74610108542146'
ORDER BY [DATE]  

+------------+----------------+-------+------------+------+
|    DATE    |       ID       | STAGE | STAGE_NEXT | FLAG |
+------------+----------------+-------+------------+------+
| 2015-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |    0 |
| 2015-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |    0 |
| 2016-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 2          |    0 |
| 2016-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 1          |    0 |
| 2016-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |    0 |
| 2016-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 2          |    0 |
| 2017-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 3          |    0 |
| 2017-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     3 | 3          |    0 |
| 2017-07-01 | 74610108542146 |     3 | 2          |    0 |
| 2017-10-01 | 74610108542146 |     2 | 1          |    1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | 1          |    0 |
| 2018-04-01 | 74610108542146 |     1 | NULL       |    0 |
+------------+----------------+-------+------------+------+
```

If the client never moved to Stage 3 then the flag for the client is always `0`

Comment: Find row, where stage_next = 1 and exists some older row for same client, where stage = 3?

Comment: How would that look like in code?

Comment: I wrote my comment almost in sql syntax ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate and update the new FLAG column from a CTE.

The update statement uses the LAG function to use the previous STAGE in the calculation of FLAG.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT ID, [DATE], FLAG,
   CASE
   WHEN STAGE = 2 
    AND STAGE_NEXT = 1 
    AND LAG(STAGE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY IIF(STAGE=2 AND STAGE_NEXT=2,0,1), [DATE]) = 3
   THEN 1
   ELSE 0
   END AS CalcFlag
  FROM T1
  WHERE ID = '10010101841033' -- optional, to target only 1 ID
)
UPDATE CTE
SET FLAG = CalcFlag
WHERE (FLAG IS NULL OR FLAG != CalcFlag);
```

The `IIF(STAGE=2 AND STAGE_NEXT=2,0,1)` in the LAG is used to make the calculation also work when the stage 2 is repeated.

Test it on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/EUSR98570)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this has the same issue as the solution from Thangadurai.B

Comment: @SergeKashlik Ah ok, well that's easy to fix, since there's already that STAGE_NEXT field. Otherwise the LEAD window function could be used for it in that calculation. Fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to make the Lag function to iterate over all lagged values of the client? For example if the stage transition was as follows 1 > 2 > 3 > 2 > 2 > 2 > 1, then the current solution will not flag it as the client was stuck in stage 2 for multiple periods before moving to stage 1.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually a hard one to do via the window functions. With LAG the default is 1 previous record, but it allows to take the value from the N'th previous record.  But without knowing which N'th record has the STAGE 3...  I'll think about it when I got more time.

Comment: @SergeKashlik Fixed. A small tweak in the ORDER BY of the LAG solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @T1 table
(
    [DATE] date,ID numeric(18,0),STAGE int,STAGE_NEXT int
)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
('2013-01-01',10010101841033,1,1   ),
('2013-04-01',10010101841033,1,3   ),
('2013-07-01',10010101841033,3,3   ),
('2013-10-01',10010101841033,3,2   ),
('2014-01-01',10010101841033,2,1   ),
('2014-04-01',10010101841033,1,1   ),
('2014-07-01',10010101841033,1,1   ),
('2014-10-01',10010101841033,1,NULL),
('2014-07-01',47820108841771,1,2)

SELECT A.DATE,A.ID,A.STAGE,A.STAGE_NEXT,
CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL AND (STAGE_NEXT=1 AND STAGE>STAGE_NEXT) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FLAG
FROM @T1 A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID AS ID
    FROM @T1
    WHERE STAGE_NEXT=3
)B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, but the solution does not take into account if the client moved to stage 2 and then stage 1 before he moved to stage 3. The flag should only be present if the client was in stage 3 and then moved to stage 1 eventually. I edited the example in the original post to reflect this condition. As per your solution on '2016-04-01' the client is flagged but should not be